# Duplicate patch in the Zoom G1Xon multi-FX pedal?

Tags: guitar-effects

Can you copy patches in the Zoom G1Xon FX pedal?

I want to select a patch and copy it to a different slot and play around with it.

Comment: What do the instructions tell you?

Comment: Haven't been able to find a way to do it in the manual, that doesn't necessarily mean this option does not exist.

Comment: @Tim should I delete this question?

Comment: One of the objectives of this site is to build a compendium of helpful facts. There may be someone else in the future who has the same problem, so with a good answer, I think there's no harm in it staying.It's always a good option to talk to customer help people, who may not have found the answer themselves, but have been told by someone who found out by accident. Too late to put in the manual.These things happen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke to Zoom's customer support and the solution is actually easy. I was searching the docs for '*copy*', '*duplicate*' etc. but it's rather just '*save*'.

To duplicate a patch, it simply needs to be saved to a new location.

This can be done by following these steps:

- Press the **MENU** button
- Select **SAVE** and press **ENTER**
- Select the location that you'd like to save the duplicate patch and press **ENTER**
- Select **YES** and press **ENTER**
- Press the **HOME** button

The patch has now been duplicated and can be modified to your liking.

Credit: Sam Barna from Zoom's customer service.